# How to whitelist/authorize test email account for OAuth app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

For Google OAuth verification purpose, I got mail from google saying that.

To proceed with the approval process, please whitelist/authorize our test email account ****@gmail.com for your app so that we may test the user sign-up process and validate the project's functionality

So How do we give the authorize test email for OAuth app.

I tired in the google cloud console, I didn't find where i should allow that test email

Answer (score 0):

You can reply directly to the email that was sent with your question.